# Multiple accordions simultaneously open. How to open only 1 JQuery accordion at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Currently open accordion is not closing when another opens.

This is the code I used, not sure where I got it wrong.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

//each accordion has a text entry and a corresponding image     
  var accordionEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-entry');
  var accordionImages = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-image'); 
  
    for ( var i = 0; i < accordionEntries.length; i++ ) {
    accordionEntries[i].dataset.target = 'accordion-image-' + i;
    accordionImages[i].classList.add('accordion-image-' + i);
  }
  

//toggles accordion open state    
  $(document).on('click', '.accordion-header', function () {
    if ($(this).is(".accordion-open")) return $(this).removeClass("accordion-open");
    var parent = $(this).closest('.accordion-entry, .accordion-image');
    if(!parent.hasClass('.accordion-open')){
        parent.toggleClass('accordion-open');
      } else {
$('.accordion-open').removeClass('accordion-open')
}
    $('.' + parent.data('target')).toggleClass('accordion-open')
    
  })

})
</script>
```

Comment: You could close all open accordions with `$('.accordion-open').removeClass('accordion-open')` each time a accordion is opened.

Comment: You want only one accordion to be open at a time? If so, you should close other open accordions as well. Use something like`.accordion-header.accordion-open` to select all open accordions and remove the `accordion-open` class.

Comment: @Geshode I did try that but it then prevents the currently open accordion from closing.

Is there a way I could limit the number '.accordion-open' to 1 in the code?

Comment: It will be great if you change your question and add the accordion HTML also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help in trying to answer the question, a colleague eventually helped me solve this. Here is the solution with comments for anyone else's benefit.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var accordionEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-entry');
  var accordionImages = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-image');
  
    for ( var i = 0; i < accordionEntries.length; i++ ) {
    accordionEntries[i].dataset.target = 'accordion-image-' + i;
    accordionImages[i].classList.add('accordion-image-' + i);
  }
      
  $(document).on('click', '.accordion-header', function () {
    // close currently opened accordion
    // add class to open clicked accordion  
    var accordionEntry = $(this).closest('.accordion-entry');
    var open = 'accordion-open';
    
    /* If the accordion that was clicked is in open state, 
    *  remove all occurrences of the 'accordion-open' class and DO NOTHING 
    *  AFTER.
    */
    if (accordionEntry.hasClass('accordion-open')) {
            accordionEntry.removeClass(open);
        $('.' + open).removeClass(open);
    } else {
        /* If the accordion that was clicked is NOT in open state, 
        *  remove all occurrences of the 'accordion-open' class and add 'accordion-open' class
        *. to the accordion that was clicked.
        */
        accordionEntry.removeClass(open);
                $('.'+ open).removeClass(open);
        accordionEntry.addClass('accordion-open');
        $('.'+ accordionEntry.data['target']).addClass(open)
          $('.'+ accordionEntry[0].dataset.target).addClass(open)
    } 
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: You're not taking very good advantage of the library you're loading. I'd either use jQuery or not, but avoid this random blend of jQuery and native JavaScript.